# Awaking Mac programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to write a custom alarm for a Mac that awakes the mac from sleep.  I think it should be done as [the Aurora app](http://metaquark.de/aurora/) seems to do it.

What methods/classes do I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented through [IOPMSchedulePowerEvent routine](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPMLib_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPMSchedulePowerEvent).  Unfortunately, the routine requires root access.  Authorization to execute privileged operation can be done using the Authorization Services framework.  One should read [“Authorizing in a Simple, Self-Restricted Application”](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-BCIGEHDI) and [“Authorizing in a Factored Application.”](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-BCIGAIAG).

Answer (score 3):

pmset can do what you need, you just need to set up your settings before it goes to sleep

Answer (score 1):

Your app can sleep the mac and ask it to wake up at a particular time look at [Power Manager](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Power_Manager/Reference/reference.html) in the documentation.

> set a timer to wake up the computer at
>   some time in the future